# ArrayList: получить отдельный элемент

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста. В обычном массиве есть такая штука `charAt` вытягивающая отдельный элемент. Есть ли что-то подобное в `ArraуList`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам отдельный элемент списка нужен?
Тогда так: `list.get(тут индекс элемента)`

Comment: У меня есть ArratList в который я запихиваю строки. Нужно проверить есть ли в этих строках конкретные символы.

Comment: ну так пробегись по всем элементам списка и делай проверку на каждый элемент: list.get(i).contain("символ")

Comment: Спасибо дошло))

Comment: @tarasman4ik1985 принято благодарить поднятием репутации + галочкой принятого ответа.

Comment: Галочку поставил,а вот поднять репутацию не могу - Недостаточно очков уважения((

Comment: Да ну ладно, не горит..)